# Calculate and plot 95% confidence interval for a given dataframe

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

How do I plot a **bar plot** from a data frame and a 95% confidence interval in the same graph using matplotlib on python(using the yerr arguement if possible). The plot should look like:
[image: Plot]

The dataframe looks like this with 3649 entries:
[image: dataframe(df)]

Comment: See the first answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30385975/seaborn-factor-plot-custom-error-bars it should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

mean = df.mean(axis = 1)
std = df.std(axis = 1)

n= df.shape[1]
yerr = std / np.sqrt(n) * stats.t.ppf(1-0.05/2, n - 1)

plt.figure()
plt.bar(range(df.shape[0]), mean, yerr = yerr) 
plt.show()
```

Good luck!