# multi index plotting

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have some data where I've manipulated the dataframe using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame([[0,0,0,3,6,5,6,1],[1,1,1,3,4,5,2,0],[2,1,0,3,6,5,6,1],[3,0,0,2,9,4,2,1],[4,0,1,3,4,8,1,1],[5,1,1,3,3,5,9,1],[6,1,0,3,3,5,6,1],[7,0,1,3,4,8,9,1]], columns=["id", "sex", "split", "group0Low", "group0High", "group1Low", "group1High", "trim"])
data

#remove all where trim == 0
trimmed = data[(data.trim == 1)]
trimmed

#create df with columns to be split
columns = ['group0Low', 'group0High', 'group1Low', 'group1High']
to_split = trimmed[columns]
to_split

level_group = np.where(to_split.columns.str.contains('0'), 0, 1)
# output: array([0, 0, 1, 1])
level_low_high = np.where(to_split.columns.str.contains('Low'), 'low', 'high')
# output: array(['low', 'high', 'low', 'high'], dtype='<U4')

multi_level_columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([level_group, level_low_high], names=['group', 'val'])
to_split.columns = multi_level_columns
to_split.stack(level='group')

sex = trimmed['sex']
split = trimmed['split']
horizontalStack = pd.concat([sex, split, to_split], axis=1)
horizontalStack

finalData = horizontalStack.groupby(['split', 'sex', 'group'])
finalData.mean()
```

My question is, how do I plot the mean data using ggplot or seaborn such that for each "split" level I get a graph that looks like this:

[image]

At the bottom of the code you can see I've tried to split up the group factor so I can separate the bars, but that resulted in an error (KeyError: 'group') and I think that is related to the way I used multi indexing

Comment: can you copy the code and the data into your question?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I would use a factor plot from seaborn.

Say you have data like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas

import seaborn
seaborn.set(style='ticks') 
np.random.seed(0)

groups = ('Group 1', 'Group 2')
sexes = ('Male', 'Female')
means = ('Low', 'High')
index = pandas.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [groups, sexes, means], 
   names=['Group', 'Sex', 'Mean']
)

values = np.random.randint(low=20, high=100, size=len(index))
data = pandas.DataFrame(data={'val': values}, index=index).reset_index()
print(data)

     Group     Sex  Mean  val
0  Group 1    Male   Low   64
1  Group 1    Male  High   67
2  Group 1  Female   Low   84
3  Group 1  Female  High   87
4  Group 2    Male   Low   87
5  Group 2    Male  High   29
6  Group 2  Female   Low   41
7  Group 2  Female  High   56
```

You can then create the factor plot with one command + plus an extra line to remove some redundant (for your data) x-labels:

```
# Note: catplot used to be called factorplot
fg = seaborn.catplot(x='Group', y='val', hue='Mean', 
                        col='Sex', data=data, kind='bar')
fg.set_xlabels('')
```

Which gives me:

[image]

Comment: This is perfect, thanks! Is there a way to plot error bars, where the error represented is standard error of the mean?

Comment: @Nem I can't look into any scope creep now. But this answers your original question. For the follow up, this SO question is the first hit I get on google searching for "seaborn error bars" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24878095/plotting-errors-bars-from-dataframe-using-seaborn-facetgrid

Comment: Wow. Reading your code carefully made me learn so much about multi-indexing and plotting that I had been struggling with previously. Really awesome for its simplicity!

Comment: The key here is `reindex`, it removes the multiindexing so the (former) indices are treated as columns.

Comment: Excel allows you to go even further with multiple layers of indexing; is this possible with factorplot?  I know you can use row=X, but is there a way to pass a list to col, for example?

Comment: @Simon error bars are plotted automatically when there is more than one data point in the category (which is averaged). For example if you remove the separation between sexes, simply like this: `fg = seaborn.factorplot(x='Group', y='val', hue='Mean', data=data, kind='bar')` you get error bars

Comment: Please note that since the [version 0.9 (July 2018)](https://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew.html#api-changes), `factorplot` has been renamed into [`catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html).

Comment: How could I get this figure, but with an extra level shown as a stacked bar chart?

Answer (score 18):

In a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39502106/2783943) I found an alternative solution by @Stein that codes the multiindex levels as different labels. Here is how it looks like for your example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import groupby
import numpy as np 
%matplotlib inline

groups = ('Group 1', 'Group 2')
sexes = ('Male', 'Female')
means = ('Low', 'High')
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [groups, sexes, means], 
   names=['Group', 'Sex', 'Mean']
)

values = np.random.randint(low=20, high=100, size=len(index))
data = pd.DataFrame(data={'val': values}, index=index)
# unstack last level to plot two separate columns
data = data.unstack(level=-1)

def add_line(ax, xpos, ypos):
    line = plt.Line2D([xpos, xpos], [ypos + .1, ypos],
                      transform=ax.transAxes, color='gray')
    line.set_clip_on(False)
    ax.add_line(line)

def label_len(my_index,level):
    labels = my_index.get_level_values(level)
    return [(k, sum(1 for i in g)) for k,g in groupby(labels)]

def label_group_bar_table(ax, df):
    ypos = -.1
    scale = 1./df.index.size
    for level in range(df.index.nlevels)[::-1]:
        pos = 0
        for label, rpos in label_len(df.index,level):
            lxpos = (pos + .5 * rpos)*scale
            ax.text(lxpos, ypos, label, ha='center', transform=ax.transAxes)
            add_line(ax, pos*scale, ypos)
            pos += rpos
        add_line(ax, pos*scale , ypos)
        ypos -= .1

ax = data['val'].plot(kind='bar')
#Below 2 lines remove default labels
ax.set_xticklabels('')
ax.set_xlabel('')
label_group_bar_table(ax, data)
```

This gives:

[image]

Comment: In `plt.Line2D`, I suggest adding `linewidth=0.8` and `color=black` to better integrate the lines with the plot frame.