# Pandas Plotting Multi Value Data over a period

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I need some help to plot some data in pandas, any help will be appreciated.

Dataframe looks like this:

```
    Item  Year Price  Quantity
0   Book  2000    $2        50
1  Table  2000   $33        44
2  Chair  2000   $21        31
3   Book  2001    $3        77
4  Table  2001   $20       500
5  Chair  2001    $2        50
6   Book  2002   $36         7
7  Table  2002  $200        50
8  Chair  2002   $44         5
```

I need to plot "Price" and "Quantity" for each item in "Item" over the years in "Year" column.

Comment: That's good for you. But what is the question? See [ask]. Note that "I need some help" is not equivalent to "Please write the code for me". At which point do you need help? Which other resources have not helped you?

Comment: Well I cann't even visualize how the plot would look like, so simply put I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about what you want but maybe you can start play from this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"Item": ["Book","Table","Chair"]*3,
              "Year":np.sort(list(range(2000,2003))*3),
              "Price":np.random.randint(2,200,9),
              "Quantity":np.random.randint(5,500,9)})
df1 = df.groupby(["Item","Year"]).apply(lambda x:x.sort_values("Year") )
del df1["Year"]
del df1["Item"]
df1.plot(kind="bar")
```

**EDIT**

Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43999896/4819376) can help you.