# Plotting discrete groups count in time axis

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have a dataframe like this:

```
    date          kind  count
    2015-08-31    1     1
    2015-10-31    1     1
    2015-12-31    1     7
    2015-12-31    5     2
    2015-12-31    2     1
    2015-12-31    3     1
    2016-01-31    1     11
    2016-01-31    2     3
    2016-01-31    5     3
    2016-01-31    4     2
    2016-01-31    3     1
```

The dates were obtained from a TimeGrouper groupby, so all Year x Month combinations are unique per kind.

Id like to produce a factorplot to plot the count per month along a time axis, broken down by kind, similar to this one, where I have the kind instead of deck: 
[image: Bidimensional Counting using Seaborn]
from the [Seaborn Documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.factorplot.html?highlight=factor%20plot#seaborn.factorplot)

Following [this question's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31845258/pandas-multi-index-plotting), I did this:

```
sns.factorplot(x='date', y='kind', data=data, kind='bar')
```

Which raised the error:

```
TypeError: ufunc add cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

So, my question is: is it possible to generate all the charts at once using Seaborn? If not, is there a simple way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need ?

```
sns.factorplot(x='date', y='count', data=data, kind='bar',col='kind')
```

[image]

Comment: It does answer my question. But all the subplots are in the same row, is there are a way to make it 'break the line'? I have many kinds

Comment: @NiloAraujo add  col_wrap=n, n is what you need, opps you got it , cheers ~