# Create barplot from string data using groupby and multiple columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, group-by

I'd like to make a bar plot in python with multiple x-categories from counts of data either "yes" or "no". I've started on some code but I believe the track I'm on in a slow way of getting to the solution I want. I'd be fine with a solution that uses either seaborn, Matplotlib, or pandas but *not* Bokeh because I'd like to make publication-quality figures that scale.

Ultimately what I want is:

- bar plot with the categories "canoe", "cruise", "kayak" and "ship" on the x-axis
- grouped-by "color", so either Green or Red
- showing the proportion of "yes" responses: so number of yes rows divided by the count of "red" and "greens" which in this case is 4 red and 4 green, but that could change.

Here's the dataset I'm working with:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [{'ship': 'Yes','canoe': 'Yes', 'cruise': 'Yes', 'kayak': 'No','color': 'Red'},{'ship': 'Yes', 'cruise': 'Yes', 'kayak': 'Yes','canoe': 'No','color': 'Green'},{'ship': 'Yes', 'cruise': 'Yes', 'kayak': 'No','canoe': 'No','color': 'Green'},{'ship': 'Yes', 'cruise': 'Yes', 'kayak': 'No','canoe': 'No','color': 'Red'},{'ship': 'Yes', 'cruise': 'Yes', 'kayak': 'Yes','canoe': 'No','color': 'Red'},{'ship': 'No', 'cruise': 'Yes', 'kayak': 'No','canoe': 'Yes','color': 'Green'},{'ship': 'No', 'cruise': 'No', 'kayak': 'No','canoe': 'No','color': 'Green'},{'ship': 'No', 'cruise': 'No', 'kayak': 'No','canoe': 'No','color': 'Red'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

This is what I've started with:

```
print(df['color'].value_counts())

red = 4 # there must be a better way to code this rather than manually. Perhaps using len()?
green = 4

# get count per type
ca = df['canoe'].value_counts()
cr = df['cruise'].value_counts()
ka = df['kayak'].value_counts()
sh = df['ship'].value_counts()
print(ca, cr, ka, sh)

# group by color
cac = df.groupby(['canoe','color'])
crc = df.groupby(['cruise','color'])
kac = df.groupby(['kayak','color'])
shc = df.groupby(['ship','color'])

# make plots 
cac2 = cac['color'].value_counts().unstack()
cac2.plot(kind='bar', title = 'Canoe by color')
```

[image]

But really what I want is all of the x-categories to be on one plot, only showing the result for "Yes" responses, and taken as the proportion of "Yes" rather than just counts. Help?

Comment: Can you attach a picture of what you expected chart should look like?

Comment: Yes @Scott Boston. I need something that looks like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31845258/pandas-multi-index-plotting/43999896#43999896 with seaborn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import groupby

data = [{'ship': 'Yes','canoe': 'Yes', 'cruise': 'Yes', 'kayak': 'No','color': 'Red'},{'ship': 'Yes', 'cruise': 'Yes', 'kayak': 'Yes','canoe': 'No','color': 'Green'},{'ship': 'Yes', 'cruise': 'Yes', 'kayak': 'No','canoe': 'No','color': 'Green'},{'ship': 'Yes', 'cruise': 'Yes', 'kayak': 'No','canoe': 'No','color': 'Red'},{'ship': 'Yes', 'cruise': 'Yes', 'kayak': 'Yes','canoe': 'No','color': 'Red'},{'ship': 'No', 'cruise': 'Yes', 'kayak': 'No','canoe': 'Yes','color': 'Green'},{'ship': 'No', 'cruise': 'No', 'kayak': 'No','canoe': 'No','color': 'Green'},{'ship': 'No', 'cruise': 'No', 'kayak': 'No','canoe': 'No','color': 'Red'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1 = df.replace(["Yes","No"],[1,0]).groupby("color").mean().stack().rename('% Yes').to_frame()


def add_line(ax, xpos, ypos):
    line = plt.Line2D([xpos, xpos], [ypos + .1, ypos],
                      transform=ax.transAxes, color='gray')
    line.set_clip_on(False)
    ax.add_line(line)

def label_len(my_index,level):
    labels = my_index.get_level_values(level)
    return [(k, sum(1 for i in g)) for k,g in groupby(labels)]

def label_group_bar_table(ax, df):
    ypos = -.1
    scale = 1./df.index.size
    for level in range(df.index.nlevels)[::-1]:
        pos = 0
        for label, rpos in label_len(df.index,level):
            lxpos = (pos + .5 * rpos)*scale
            ax.text(lxpos, ypos, label, ha='center', transform=ax.transAxes)
            add_line(ax, pos*scale, ypos)
            pos += rpos
        add_line(ax, pos*scale , ypos)
        ypos -= .1


colorlist = ['green','red']
cp = sns.color_palette(colorlist)

ax = sns.barplot(x=df1.index, y='% Yes', hue = df1.index.get_level_values(0), data=df1, palette=cp)
#Below 2 lines remove default labels
ax.set_xticklabels('')
ax.set_xlabel('')
label_group_bar_table(ax, df1)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly sure if I understand the question correctly. It looks like it would make more sense to look at the proportion of answers per boat type *and* color.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
data = [{'ship': 'Yes','canoe': 'Yes', 'cruise': 'Yes', 'kayak': 'No','color': 'Red'},{'ship': 'Yes', 'cruise': 'Yes', 'kayak': 'Yes','canoe': 'No','color': 'Green'},{'ship': 'Yes', 'cruise': 'Yes', 'kayak': 'No','canoe': 'No','color': 'Green'},{'ship': 'Yes', 'cruise': 'Yes', 'kayak': 'No','canoe': 'No','color': 'Red'},{'ship': 'Yes', 'cruise': 'Yes', 'kayak': 'Yes','canoe': 'No','color': 'Red'},{'ship': 'No', 'cruise': 'Yes', 'kayak': 'No','canoe': 'Yes','color': 'Green'},{'ship': 'No', 'cruise': 'No', 'kayak': 'No','canoe': 'No','color': 'Green'},{'ship': 'No', 'cruise': 'No', 'kayak': 'No','canoe': 'No','color': 'Red'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

ax = df.replace(["Yes","No"],[1,0]).groupby("color").mean().transpose().plot.bar(color=["g","r"])
ax.set_title('Proportion "Yes" answers per of boat type and color')
plt.show()
```

[image]

This means e.g. that 25% of all green canoes answered "yes".

Comment: Nice, you could get to the data with `df.set_index('color').eq('Yes').mean(level='color').T` too.

Comment: Thanks yeah I'd like something like this though with multiple x-axis categories: stackoverflow.com/questions/31845258/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are exactly looking for it or not, let me know if it works.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tidy_df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['color'] ,var_name='variable', value_name='value')
total_df = tidy_df[['variable']].groupby('variable').size().reset_index()
tidy_df = tidy_df.groupby(['color', 'variable', 'value']).size().reset_index()

merged_df = pd.merge(tidy_df, total_df, on='variable', how='left', suffixes=('_left', '_right'))
merged_df['proportion'] = merged_df['0_left']/merged_df['0_right']

# merged_df[merged_df['value'] == 'Yes']

palette ={"Green":"green","Red":"red"} # optional you can select your own
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
sns.barplot(x='variable', y='proportion', hue='color',data=merged_df[merged_df['value'] == 'Yes'], palette=palette)
plt.xticks(rotation=65)
#plt.savefig('numbers.png')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi I want something like this though with multiple x-axis categories: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31845258/pandas-multi-index-plotting/43999896#43999896