# Plot dataframe with two-column index and show x-tick values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Suppose I have dataframe, which has index composed of two columns and I want to plot it:

```
import pandas
from matplotlib import pyplot as plot
df=pandas.DataFrame(data={'floor':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3],'room':[1,2,3,1,1,2,1,3],'count':[1, 1, 3,2,2,4,1,5]})
df2=df.groupby(['floor','room']).sum()
df2.plot()
plot.show()
```

The above example will result in a plot where row numbers are used for x axis and no tick labels. **Are there any facilities to use the index instead?**

Say, I'd like to have x axis separated into even sections for first column of index and spread out points values of second index column inside those sections.

Comment: @jezrael, no, I need both index columns used to determine point position on x axis and the xtick label.

Comment: Try this SO Post.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/43999896/6361531