# Seaborn not changing data in lineplot facets of facetgrid

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I'm trying to use a `seaborn` `facetgrid` to plot timeseries data from a large file.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sb
import pandas as pd

df_ready=pd.read_hdf('data.hdf')

... # drop null rows, etc.

fg=sb.FacetGrid(data=df_ready[ df_ready.medium == 'LSM'],row='ARS853',col='fMLP',legend_out=True)
fg.map(sb.lineplot,data=df_ready[ df_ready.medium == 'LSM'],x='qtime',y='A',hue='RNA',hue_order=['siC','si6','si7','si8'])
```

The code produces this plot:[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLGFh.png), which as you can see is identical in all four panels. I have verified using `seaborn.lineplot` that the data itself is actually distinguishable between the four cases, so clearly I am misusing `seaborn` somehow. A similar issue occurs when I change the axes (e.g. `row='RNA'` and `hue='ARS853'`) Can anybody tell me how to plot the data faithfully (and still use `facetgrid`)?

Comment: You would strongly benefit from providing a [mcve] of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

D'oh!

The answer is that I'm passing kwargs to the mapped function, which is not supported. They should be positional instead. cf. [Plotting errors bars from dataframe using Seaborn FacetGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24878095/plotting-errors-bars-from-dataframe-using-seaborn-facetgrid)