# Visualize distance to expected value in a scatter plot in Seaborn

Tags: python, distance, seaborn, scatter-plot, errorbar

I want to create a scatter plot (for discrete x and only one dot per x) and for each dot, I want to visualize the distance to its expected value with a line, preferably in Seaborn.

[Basically, I want something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eo78Z.png) (taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24878095/plotting-errors-bars-from-dataframe-using-seaborn-facetgrid)), but I want the error bars to only go into one direction, not up **and** down. The line of the error bar should end where my expected value is.

Edit: An example.

Some code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

some_y=[1,2,3,7,9,10]
expected_y=[2, 2.5, 2, 5, 8.5, 9.5]

plt.plot(some_y, ".", color="blue")
plt.plot(expected_y, ".", color="red")
plt.show()
```

[Looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnwIX.png)

[What I would like to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9oZD.png)

Also, it does not have to look **exactly** like this. Just something in this direction.

Comment: A line is produced with `plt.plot`. Several lines are produced with several `plt.plot`, or a `LineCollection`. A scatter is produced with `plt.scatter`. Maybe you want to go into detail of what you have tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: Maybe, my description was a bit unclear. I updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way to produce several lines is to use a `LineCollection`. To also show the dots, you would use an additional `scatter`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

some_y=[1,2,3,7,9,10]
expected_y=[2, 2.5, 2, 5, 8.5, 9.5]

x = np.repeat(np.arange(len(some_y)), 2).reshape(len(some_y), 2)
y = np.column_stack((some_y, expected_y))
verts = np.stack((x,y), axis=2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_collection(LineCollection(verts))
ax.scatter(np.arange(len(some_y)), some_y)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Yep, that's it. Thank you!